# Which PHP library to choose to handle AMF communication?

Tags: cakephp, amf, amfphp, weborb

I'm looking for a PHP library to handle AMF communication with a Flash client app. My server will be running PHP 5.3.5 and a cakePHP app.

I tried the cakeAMF, cakeAMFPHP and Cpamf cake plugins but they all are pretty old and not updated anymore. Also I'm encountering a plethora of issues integrating them in cakePHP 1.3 on PHP 5.3.5

So I'm now turning to the next players in line : WebORB, sabreAMF and Zend AMF.

Have you tested them already, and if so, which one would you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried integrating any of those with CakePHP, but I've worked with the old AMFPHP, ZendAMF, and WebORB, and ZendAMF is easily the best choice for integrating into an existing app. As far as I understand it, the author of AMFPHP created ZendAMF, so it should be the fastest and most correct AMF implementation available for PHP.

I've done the same thing you did with a Symfony app, and I used the old AMFPHP for that. It turned out okay in the end, but there were some issues to deal with because AMFPHP wasn't really designed for that. Plus, a bunch of stuff has been fixed in ZendAMF that's kind of broken in AMFPHP.

Comment: Does ZendAMF require the Zend framework to work ? I wouldn't like to have to had the whole Zend stack on top of cakePHP.

Comment: ZendAMF only has a few dependencies on the whole Zend framework - it's mostly standalone. You can download a package of just the dependencies for ZendAMF at http://framework.zend.com/download/amf.

Answer (score 0):

I migrated the cakephp 1.3 with amfphp to cakephp 2.0, seems to work. I'm willing to make it available on github if there is any interest

Answer (score 0):

There is a fast and reliable PHP AMF3 extension to try out:

http://neoxic.me/php-amf3/

It allows two native functions amf3_encode() and amf3_decode() to be employed instead of bringing in a relatively large framework.